# How do I stop WANdisco Subversion conflicting with Apache24?

Tags: apache, svn

**EDIT:**

I did find out a few key things:

1. In Windows 7, (Maybe other OS's?)  There is a `hosts` file.  That `hosts` file controls custom local URL addresses.  You can define a custom name for a local host URL.  For example:  `mywebserver.localhost`.   If you want your browser to serve local files from your computer with a custom URL name, you can set that in the `hosts` file.  The `hosts` file is located in `Drive:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`.  If you don't have permissions to write to that file, you'll get an error message stating the the file isn't found, or something like that when you try to save the file.
2. Apache has a `conf` folder with a file in it named: `httpd.conf`.  That controls the configuration directives for Apache.
3. If you want to link PHP to Apache, PHP has a `PHP.ini` file that needs to be configured.

**END EDIT**

I installed WANdisco Subversion, for Windows7 32bit (Link for reference)

[Subversion - Version Control](http://www.wandisco.com/subversion/download#windows)

and it installed with APACHE 2.2 in a sub-folder.
The only reason I install Subversion, was that a Google help page:

[Install the Google Client Library for PHP](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-php#step_2_install_the_google_client_library)

stated that it was required to download the source code needed for the Google API PHP Client Library.

Then I installed PHP and Apache 2.4 in their own folders, and configured the `C:\Apache24\conf\httpd.conf` file to point to a local webserver.  (Along with some other configurations)

[YouTube install Apache on Windows 7](http://youtu.be/17qhikHv5hY)

The path in my operating system is:

> C:\Program Files\WANdisco\Subversion\Apache2\bin;C:\Program
>   Files\WANdisco\Subversion;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:Python27;C:Python27\Scripts;C:\php

The localhost in my web browser will load an HTML file from the Apache set up in the Subversion Directory, but not from the C:\Apache24 directory.

How am I going to keep both Apache installations, and get the localhost to load HTML files from someplace other than the `C:\Program Files\WANdisco\Subversion` directory?  I'm tempted to just delete the Apache folder from `WANdisco\Subversion`.  Or just unistall the whole Subversion software.  I'll probably never use it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds to me like you don't need a server install of Subversion, but only the client.

I'd suggest uninstalling the version you have an installing the Client only download, which won't come with Apache httpd.

Comment: I'm just learning about Apache web server, and Subversion.  So, I'm just fumbling around.  I did uninstall Subversion, and got a local Apache server to run the way I want it to.  (Thanks to a YouTube video)  If for some reason I need Subversion again, I'll look for a client only version.